# OPENSHIFT DIY Tomcat cartridge setenv.sh script not picking up OPENSHIFT vars

Tags: tomcat, openshift, setenv

Steps :

- Followed steps in Shipley's "Learning Openshift" chapter on DIY
- Created a DIY cartridge
- ssh'd in
- sent to app-root/data
- wget .....tomcat 8
- untar
- set up conf/server
- set up conf/tomcat-users
- started up - worked - could access Tomcat home page

I want to replace the hard-coded address and port vals in the conf/server.xml file with the $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP and $OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT env vars.

When i just put those vars in directly - it didn't work.

I have gotten as far as learning that the reason is because the $OPENSHIFT_* vars are not being passed into the JVM properly - which is fine.

To get around this - i thought I could just add a few sections into the bin/setenv.sh file in order to capture them into my own vars and then use my vars in the server.xml file, eg,

MY_IP=$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP
MY_PORT=$OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT

My current issue is that the above statements aren't working inside setenv.sh

I can execute these commands from a command line terminal session and have the $MY_* vars retain the values but when they are put inside setenv and ./setenv.sh is run - the vals come out as empty strings.

Constructive /helpful thoughts ?

tia

Answer (score 0):

When you run setenv by running it directly, the MY_* environment variables will only be available inside the setenv script.

When you want the variables to be available outside the setenv script, you need to `source setenv` or `. setenv`.

If you want these variables to be available to subprocesses create from your shell, you need to `export` your environment variables.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the additional info. What I'm trying to implement is the ability for this cartridge to be moved around to different nodes [if it has to be] w/o requiring a manual edit of the ../conf/server.xml file.  I'm supposed to be able to use environment variable substitution to accomplish this....it does work not in an OS environment....i'm just having a small issue with the correct syntax / sequence of accomplishing this when in an OS gear. Thanks again.

Comment: If you want to know how they do the variable substitution on OpenShift, take a look at the following script: https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews/bin/tomcat lines 58 - 87.